# Using events to pass information to another thread, not executing concurrently

Tags: java, multithreading, events

In the following code I have a recurring timer that fetches a list of messages from an online queue. The goal of this code was to test that it is possible to have the recurring timer thread only fetch the messages and pass the results to the main thread for handling.

Instead what I see is that despite the event listener being in the main thread, all actions called after the event is raised, in the recurring timer thread, **always** finish after the events have been handled. I understand that it is possible for this to happen occasionally depending on which thread is on the cpu at any given time, but I should still see the print statements interwoven every now and again.

I have also tested this effect by adding approximately 50 messages to the queue and I still see the same results.

My code is below

```
public class Service implements NewWindowEventArgsListener
{

private final static String accessKey = 
        "secret";

private final static String secretKey = 
        "secret";

private final static String AWSSQSServiceUrl =
        "secret";


private boolean IsWindowing = false;
private ScheduledExecutorService _windowTimer;
private long SQSWindow = 60000;
private NewWindowEventArgs handler = new NewWindowEventArgs();
private static List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<Message>();


public void StartProcesses()
{
    if(this.IsWindowing)
    {
        return;
    }

    handler.addListener(this);

    this._windowTimer = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

    Runnable task = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            WindowCallback();
        }
    };

    this._windowTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task,
            0, SQSWindow, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    IsWindowing = true;
}

private void WindowCallback()
{
    Date now = new Date();
    System.out.println("The service is running: " + now);

    int numberOfMessages = 0;
    ArrayList<String> attributes = new ArrayList<String>();
    AWSCredentials cred = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
    ClientConfiguration config = new ClientConfiguration();
    config.setMaxErrorRetry(10);

    AmazonSQS client = new AmazonSQSClient(cred, config);

    client.setEndpoint(AWSSQSServiceUrl);

    System.out.println("Receiving messages from the Queue.\n");
    ReceiveMessageRequest receiveMessageRequest = 
            new ReceiveMessageRequest(AWSSQSServiceUrl);

    receiveMessageRequest.setMaxNumberOfMessages(10);

    GetQueueAttributesRequest numMessages = 
            new GetQueueAttributesRequest(AWSSQSServiceUrl); 

    attributes.add("ApproximateNumberOfMessages");
    numMessages.setAttributeNames(attributes);

    numberOfMessages = Integer.valueOf(
            (client.getQueueAttributes(numMessages)).getAttributes().
            get("ApproximateNumberOfMessages")).intValue();

    System.out.println("Expected number of Messages: " + numberOfMessages);

    do
    {
        messages.addAll(client.receiveMessage(receiveMessageRequest).
            getMessages());
    }while(messages.size() < numberOfMessages);

    System.out.println("Starting the printing of messages");

    if ( messages.size() > 0)
    {
        System.out.println("A message exists!");
        System.out.println();
        handler.NewWindowEvent(messages);
        System.out.println("//////////////////////////////////");
        System.out.println("\tEmptying message list");
        messages.clear();
        System.out.println("\tMessage list empty");
        System.out.println("//////////////////////////////////");
        System.out.println();
    }
}

@Override
public void JetstreamService_NewWindow(List<Message> messages) {
    System.out.println("Number of messages: " + messages.size() + "\n");

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    try 
    {
        for (Message message : messages)
        {

            //System.out.println(message.getBody() + "\n");
            //byte[] bytes = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(message.getBody());

            //String messageBody = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");

            //System.out.println(messageBody + "\n");

            AmazonSNSMessage b;

            b = mapper.readValue(message.getBody(), AmazonSNSMessage.class);

            String subject = b.getSubject().trim().toLowerCase();
            System.out.println(subject);

            if (subject.equals("heartbeatevent"))
            {
                HeartbeatEvent heartbeat = new HeartbeatEvent();

                heartbeat.Deserialize(b.getMessage());

                System.out.println(heartbeat.getHeaderEventTime() + "\n");
            }

            else if(subject.equals("logicaldeviceaddedevent"))
            {
                LogicalDeviceAddedEvent logical = 
                        new LogicalDeviceAddedEvent();

                logical.Deserialize(b.getMessage());

                System.out.println(
                        logical.getLogicalDeviceAddedEventRegion() + "\n");
            }

            else if(subject.equals("logicaldeviceremovedevent"))
            {
                LogicalDeviceRemovedEvent logical = 
                        new LogicalDeviceRemovedEvent();

                logical.Deserialize(b.getMessage());

                System.out.println(
                        logical.getHeaderEventId());

                System.out.println(
                        logical.getHeaderEventTime() + "\n");
            }
        }
    } catch (JsonParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
```

Can someone please explain why the messages are not being handled in the main thread, or offer and explanation on why the clear messages print statements always occur after all of the messages have been handled.

Comment: Please respect Java naming conventions (method names should begin with a lowercase letter and so do instance variables); that makes it easier for people to help

Comment: Any reason why you are not using, say, a `LinkedBlockingQueue`? This is actually much more suitable for solving a producer/consumer problem than events

Comment: The main thread is not supposed to wait on the recurring thread at any point. The message event is intended to act like an interrupt, where the main tread will possibly be listing for many different events and handling them appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand what you don't understand but I'll try to clarify what happens:

- you start the timer and it starts to wait for the next schedule
- when it's time for the timer callback to be executed **a thread is chosen**: not your main thread that is busy in a UI events loop or waiting or working, but another thread; e.g. in .Net a timer implementation uses a thread from the **global threads pool**
- so your callback, i.e. WindowCallback, executes on this thread **synchronously** (seems like there is nothing asynchronous in the code)
- it arrives at **handler.NewWindowEvent(messages)**: here we must distinguish 2 orthogonal notions: the **semantics**, raising an event, and the way it is executed, like any method call, **on the same thread, synchronously**
- so **JetstreamService_NewWindow** is executed, handles the messages and returns
- execution resumes just after handler.NewWindowEvent and clears the messages list

Here is a schema (ala UML) that sums it up:

O represents the start of a method

X its ends

```
    timer  WindowCallback   NewWindowEvent  JetstreamService_NewWindow
    O
    |        
    +------->O
    |        |
    |        +---------------->O
    |        |                 |
    |        |                 +------------------>O
    |        |                 |                   |
    |        |                 +<------------------X
    |        |                 |
    |        +<----------------X
    |        |clear
    |<-------X
    X
```

Well, I'm definitely not an artist :(

To sum it up even more: starting from the timer ticks there is **only one thread of execution** that runs all your methods synchronously one after the other.

Hope this help

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, it was really helpful. Since this is the case, do you have any suggestions on how I would make the main thread execute the raised event?

Comment: There is generally no need for using a specific thread to run a treatment, except for GUI toolkits that restrict interactions with their objects to the UI thread. Why do you want to run it on the main thread?

Comment: There is concern that if there are enough events in the queue that handling them within the timer thread will cause a delay in the timer execution. It is also possible for the information received from the messages to be displayed in the GUI. If this thread can call call commands to display the information, or there is no threat of delay in the timer then there is no issue.

Comment: You'll have the delay whatever the thread you use. Moreover keep in mind that you should execute the less possible code on the UI thread because doing so will freeze the UI: so you should handle the computation on the timer thread and then at the last moment push a small treatment on the UI thread. If you have more notifications than what you can handle then you should use a different timing.